# How do i solve this: Node RED App not deploying

Tags: node-red

I am currently following this tutorial: https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-node-red-starter-application/

However, in step 3, I receive an error message:

The application manager cannot find the service. Incident ID: f7f7970a-5ae5-4d4d-a1c7-a4a6c6a32369

Note:

- It may be an account issue because my account was suspended and then reactivated and now i have 6 month lite Academic voucher applied.
- Cloud foundry is working fine
- This is my first App

This is a unique problem, everyone in my class did not have this issue.

Thank you

Comment: Check what region you've created the application, cloudant instance and tool chain in. Compare it with others in your class who have got beyond this step.

Comment: Hi, i have already done this and tried different locations. Thank you 

Answer (score 0):

Just create another account. I too faced the same issue and tried different combinations of locations as well. Nothing worked. So, if you have another mail ID, do create one with it. These kind of errors occur at times.